# Backbone.Marionette, collection items in a grid (no table)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, marionette

I am trying to figure how to effectivly move a collection of models to a grid pattern in the view.

This is a question about Row/Column principle of a simple collection.

Say I have the following *Collection*:

```
[
    {id: 1, title="test 1"},
    {id: 2, title="test 2"},
    {id: 3, title="test 3"},
    {id: 4, title="test 4"},
    {id: 5, title="test 5"},
    {id: 6, title="test 6"}
]
```

I want it to be displayed such as:

Grid:

"test 1" "test 2" "test 3"

"test 4" "test 5" "test 6"

In twitter bootstrap I would write this:

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">test 1</div>
        <div class="span4">test 2</div>
        <div class="span4">test 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">test 4</div>
        <div class="span4">test 5</div>
        <div class="span4">test 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried overriding the appendHtml of my `CompositeView`:

```
appendHtml: function(compositeView, itemView, index){
    ... 
    if ((index % 3) === 0  || lastelement){
        ... append
    }
}
```

More directly this implementation:

```
                    this.cacheColumns.push(itemView.el);



                    // If current index (+1) has rest of 0 when we devide it by column amount 

                    // OR

                    // End of array loop.

                    if (((index+1) % this.colAmount) === 0 || index == this.collection.length-1){

                            var row = $('<div class="row-fluid" />');

                            for(var i = 0; i < this.cacheColumns.length; i++){

                                    row.append(this.cacheColumns[i]);                               

                            }

                            this.cacheColumns = [];

                            collectionView.$(".jsListImages").append(row);

                    }
```

This method however generated lots of bugs, weird bugs when adding / deleting items.

Should create a method that generates a collection of 3 items a new collection?

So instead of:

```
Collection -> Item
```

I can do

```
Collection -> Collection -> Item
```

Now I also tried this implementation, didn't work as expected when adding / deleting items, also generated unknown items when using back/forward arrows to go into the specific page:

```
View.ImageMultiUploader = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template : '#common-multi-imageuploader-composite',

    itemView : ImageMultiItem,

    colAmount : 3, // How many columns we got.

    cacheColumns : [], // appendHtml uses this. don't change.

    /**

     * Custom implementation of appendHtml, using this, we can use row/column

     * principle on a collection. 

     */

    appendHtml : function(collectionView, itemView, index) {

        this.cacheColumns.push(itemView.el);

        // If current index (+1) has rest of 0 when we devide it by column amount 

        // OR

        // End of array loop.

        if (((index + 1) % this.colAmount) === 0
                || index == this.collection.length - 1) {

            var row = $('<div class="row-fluid" />');

            for ( var i = 0; i < this.cacheColumns.length; i++) {

                row.append(this.cacheColumns[i]);

            }

            this.cacheColumns = [];

            collectionView.$(".jsListImages").append(row);

        }

    },

    onRender : function() {

        console.log(this.collection)

    }

});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into nearly the identical issue, and @g00fy's answer got my pointed in the right direction. In an early iteration, I used the parse() method on my collection to reformat the data as groups of "rows" and "columns". What I later ran into was wanting to use the same dataset for a different use -- but my parse solution was breaking that.

Rather than create a second collection + fetch, I'm modifying the data during the outer view's  initialize. Here is the relevant code:

```
Views.GridRow = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#row-template",
    itemView: Views.GridItem,
    itemViewContainer: "div.row-fluid",
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(this.model.attributes));
    }
});

Views.Grid = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#grid-template",
    itemView: Views.GridRow,
    itemViewContainer: "section",
    initialize: function() {
        var grid = this.collection.groupBy(function(list, iterator) {
            return Math.floor(iterator / 4); // 4 == number of columns
        });
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(grid));
    }
});
```

And here's a working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanbuchs/c72Vg/

What I couldn't figure out was how to pass the grouped data from the grid to the rows as something I could access easily ("this.collection"). What I ended up doing was to move the data into new generic Collection objects, and at the row I'm getting it from the model attributes. Not saying this is *the* way to go, but it works.

Comment: This was awesome! Also found that I didn't need the templates and could simply specify the `tagName` and `className` attributes on the views. For example, on `Views.GridRow` you could use `className: "row-fluid"` and forgo the template, if you wanted. Great work!

Comment: More recent versions of Marionette also allow passing childViewOptions. This means you can move the code of Views.GridRow.initialize to the Views.Grid class as the option `childViewsOptions: function(model, idx){collection:new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(model.attributes)}`. Views.GridRow is now decoupled from the whole grouping process and it can be any view that renders a collection.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use: *CompositeView (TableView)* -> *CompositeView (RowView)* -> *ItemView (ColumnView)*

1st *CompositeView (TableView)* would render the table and pass 3 objects from collection to *RowView*.

You would need to change some internals in *TableView* to pass 3 objects to *RowView* instead of one, or you could restructure your collection to be grouped in rows example:

```
[
    [{id: 1, title="test 1"},        {id: 2, title="test 2"},        {id: 3, title="test 3"}],
    [{id: 4, title="test 4"},        {id: 5, title="test 5"},        {id: 6, title="test 6"}]
]
```

2nd *CompositeView (RowView)* would render row and each object in *ItemView*